# I can't modify RIP register on 64-bit linux

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb, 64-bit, stack-overflow

I'm trying to learn about stack overflow but all that i read was about 32-bit. My processor is 64-bit and i am having the following problem:

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void return_input (void)
{ 
char array[30]; 
gets (array); 
printf("%s\n", array); 
}
int main() 
{ 
return_input(); 
return 0;
```

}

GDB disas main:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000040055f <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400560 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400563 <+4>: callq  0x40053d <return_input>
   0x0000000000400568 <+9>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040056d <+14>:    pop    %rbp
   0x000000000040056e <+15>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

GDB disas return_input:

```
   Dump of assembler code for function return_input:
   0x000000000040053d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040053e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400541 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000000000400545 <+8>: lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400549 <+12>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040054c <+15>:    callq  0x400440 <gets@plt>
   0x0000000000400551 <+20>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400555 <+24>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400558 <+27>:    callq  0x400410 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000040055d <+32>:    leaveq 
   0x000000000040055e <+33>:    retq
```

Compile instructions:

```
cc -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -ggdb overflow.c -o overflow
or
cc -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -z execstack overflow.c -o overflow
```

Well, i am trying to modify RIP to 0x0000000000400563, and make that the code ask two times for the input, but it dosnt work.

I found that the code crash with an input of 40 caracters. So i tryied with the following input:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x63\x05\x40\x00

break *0x000000000040055

(gdb) x/12x $rsp
0x7fffffffe280: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe290: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe2a0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x3336785c  0x3530785c
(gdb)
```

Normal input without crashes:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

break *0x000000000040055

(gdb) x/12x $rsp
0x7fffffffe280: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffe290: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x00400041  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe2a0: 0xffffe2b0  0x00007fff  0x00400568  0x00000000
(gdb)
```

As you can see, here the stack points to 0x00400568 but with the input for controll the RIP points to 0x3336785c. Why? I can't inject the address in the right way.

Thank you for your time. I will really appreaciate any answer.

Comment: _GDB disas return_input:..._ Is `main`'s disassembly here as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So i tryied with the following input:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x63\x05\x40\x00
```

You are putting literal characters `'\\', '6', '3', '\\', '0', '5'` etc. (i.e. their ASCII codes) into the buffer. But you are *supposed* to put the actual number 0x400563 in there, not ASCII codes for `'4', '0'` etc.

The usual way this is accomplished is by piping output from e.g.

```
perl -e 'print "A" x 20, "\x63", "\x05", "\x40", "\x00"'
```

to the input of your program.

Update:

> But how i put on gdb "perl -e ..."

The usual way to accomplish this is by putting desired output into a file:

```
printf "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x63\x05\x40\x00" > /tmp/t
```

and then using GDB input redirection:

```
(gdb) run < /tmp/t
```

Comment: When i do "printf "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x63\x05\x40\x00" | ./overflow" it prints two times. But how i put on gdb "perl -e 'print "A" x 20, "\x63", "\x05", "\x40", "\x00"'". I mean when?